# What is the correct way to use typography in Material Design 3?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components

**In material design 3, there are 15 types of typography tokens:**

1. textAppearanceDisplayLarge (57sp)
2. textAppearanceDisplayMedium (45sp)
3. textAppearanceDisplaySmall (36sp)
4. textAppearanceHeadlineLarge (32sp)
5. textAppearanceHeadlineMedium (28sp)
6. textAppearanceHeadlineSmall (24sp)
7. textAppearanceTitleLarge (22sp)
8. textAppearanceTitleMedium (16sp)
9. textAppearanceTitleSmall (14sp)
10. textAppearanceBodyLarge (16sp)
11. textAppearanceBodyMedium (14sp)
12. textAppearanceBodySmall (12sp)
13. textAppearanceLabelLarge (14sp)
14. textAppearanceLabelMedium (12sp)
15. textAppearanceLabelSmall (11sp)

**Here is how I used the tokens:**

***values\dimens.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textSizeDisplay">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeHeadline">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeTitle">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeBody">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeLabel">11sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

***values-large\dimens.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textSizeDisplay">45sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeHeadline">28sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeTitle">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeBody">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeLabel">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

***values-xlarge\dimens.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textSizeDisplay">57sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeHeadline">32sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeTitle">22sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeBody">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textSizeLabel">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

***Depending on the text type, I use the tokens***

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    ...
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeTitle" />
```

**The question:**

*Did I use the tokens in the right way or there is another way to use the tokens?*

*Also, I know when I should use **Display and Body**, But when should I use **Headline, Title, and Label** because I think they are the same?*

*I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040586) and [this](https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/applying-type) but still don't know when should I use **Headline, Title, and Label.***

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Typography.md) to implement the material 3 type scale (link can be found on the material 3 website in [this section](https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/overview#1f5c8041-ffa4-4c3a-8e30-a24cd5f6c5af)  of the typography documentation by the way).

As a short explanation of how to implement:

1. your app theme should inherit from a `Material3` theme, for example:

```xml
<style name=Theme.MyApp" parent ="Theme.material3.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- add additional properties here -->
</style>
```

Don't forget to specify your theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<application
     android:theme"@style/Theme.MyApp"
     ...
     />
```

2. then if you don't need to customize each individual material style, simply use them as needed:

```xml
<TextView
    style="?textAppearanceDisplaySmall" 
    ... 
    />
```

3. if on the other hand you ***do*** need to customize each style, then follow [the guide found on Github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Typography.md#customization):

```xml
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.DisplaySmall" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.DisplaySmall">
  ...
  <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_font</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">64sp</item>
  <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
  ...
</style>
```

then in your theme.xml:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="textAppearanceDisplaySmall">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.DisplaySmall</item>
  ...
</style>
```

As for `Headline` vs. `Title` vs. `Label`, the documentation you linked seems clear to me:

- use the `Headline` style for high emphasis text that is short
- use `Title` style for medium emphasis text that may be longer

So for example if you have a card with a title, you may use the `Headline` style if it says "Ada Lovelace" but  `Title` if it says "Design is where science and art break even".

- Label is very clearly different than the other two above since the documentation says:

> Label styles are **smaller**, utilitarian styles, used for things like the text inside components or for **very small text** in the content body, such as **captions**. **Buttons**, for example, use the label large style.